# Sharepoint 2010 get items from multilookup

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

I have field in my list with type:

```
        Type="LookupMulti"
```

I need in c# code get values from this field but i cannot understand how to do that.
My tries:

```
  public static void GetFields(this SPListItem item)
    {
        var messages = item.GetLookup(new Guid("{0B72A4E1-FFFF-4D45-B07A-197D46D2989C}"));
    //messages  - no Value property..
        var test=item.Fields[new Guid("{0B72A4E1-FFFF-4D45-B07A-197D46D2989C}")];
        // var collection=new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(test.ToString()); - empty

    }
```

How can i get items from this item.Fields[...] lookup selected items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `.Fields` from the setter to test:

```
public static void GetFields(this SPListItem item)
{
    var test=item[new Guid("{0B72A4E1-FFFF-4D45-B07A-197D46D2989C}")];
    var collection=new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(test.ToString());
}
```

You don't want to pass the [SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412205.aspx) to [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx), you want to pass the [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468836.aspx) of the [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx).